# What is the likelihood of a NAS getting hacked?

Tags: network, attacks, attack-prevention, internet

I'm looking at NAS (network attached storage) to use as one of several backup storage devices to store my data, since I cannot find a DAS (direct attached storage) with RAID functionality (all of the devices I've looked at seemed to be NAS). I'm worried mainly about the security of the NAS because it will contain sensitive data such as pictures. What is the likelihood that I may be a target of a hacker? How likely is he to get access?

Comment: I'm not sure there would be any way for anyone to answer your question. Who a hacker chooses to target, and when, is up to the hacker. As for the functionality of the NAS, that's a question for the NAS vendor.

Comment: Normally you'd have NAS storage mounted on your PC as another drive over ethernet via switch. So if someone gains access to your PC, he will be able to browse your NAS as well. But, if you encrypt the backups, then they will be secure even if someone will nick your NAS from building. That's assuming you are on home network where all is cabled and no WiFi.

Comment: Consumer NAS units in general have a horrible history of security.  For example, Synology while feature rich has had numerous critical issues.  Often NAS units are running old and (unpatched or slowly patched) SAMBA.  Also recall Asus offers NAS with USB connected hard drives to routers (bad idea).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A NAS is not necessarily connected to the Internet, e.g. my NAS has a local 192.168 address which is not routed. In addition I have blocked that IP address from getting Internet access through the DSL router. The NAS itself is protected via username and password.

There are a few attack vectors, of course:

1. the DSL router can be hacked. Getting root access on the DSL router, the intruder could reach the NAS. Then, the attacker still needs to hack the user account of the NAS.
2. my PC could be hacked. Getting access to my PC would immediately give access to the NAS as well, because I authenticate with the same username and password. You could choose different username and password to get a higher security. If so, the attacker would need to transfer data from the NAS via my PC to the Internet.

Depending on your backup strategy, you can protect the backup by an additional password or even encrypt it.

That said, if

- you're a bit careful,
- run an up-to-date virus scanner,
- configure your network and DSL router carefully,
- do not browse as admin,
- install updates frequently

you'll likely not run into problems. I have a NAS setup like that since ~10 years and don't know of any issues.

If you need the NAS only for backups, you can turn it off when unused and just turn it on e.g. every 2 weeks for making the backup.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally assumed that your NAS is set for local access and not exposed to the external network via port forwarding or DMZ ... if this is not the case please update your question accordingly.

Given this assumption, the NAS can be considered as vulnerable as the rest of your internal network.  If you download a virus on a computer with access to the NAS it could be compromised.  If let other people use your computer and or your network and or have wifi access with no password, weak password, or WEP encryption it could be compromised. The NAS itself is just another network device ... it will be no more or less secure than your networked printer.

In the grand scheme of things, the attack surface of a Linux based NAS on a private network with decently tech savy users is pretty limited.  I have managed multiple NAS devices both personal and professional over the years and have had more issues with hardware failure than malicious intent.